# Why this for in statement return 0 and 1?

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop

Can anyone please help me break down these code and explain in detail why it returns 0 and 1?

For in statement is supposed to return the property of an object. I could not figure out why this code return 0 and 1. Can anyone explain in plain language? Thanks in advance for any help!

```
var JSON = {
            "users":[
                {
                    "name":"dennis",
                    "age":25
                },
                {
                    "name":"zoe",
                    "age":25               
                }
            ]
};

for (var prop in JSON.users){
    console.log(prop);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `JSON.users` is an array, the keys are the indexes, 0 and 1 (you can retrieve the elements using `JSON.users[0]` and `JSON.users[1]`).